# Visualizing the Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, statistics

I've understand in layman terms what is stated by the weak law of large numbers:

$P(\left | \frac{X_{1}+...+X_{n}}{n} \right |-\mu \geq \epsilon )\rightarrow 0 $       as $n\rightarrow +\infty $

Unfortunatly, i'm not able to visually imagine the shape of the random variable $\left | \frac{X_{1}+...+X_{n}}{n} \right |-\mu $. Can you help me showing how this random variable takes shape?

Answer (score 2):

Some simulations per request in comment:

Convergence of running sample averages to population mean is shown for
three distributions. Speed of convergence of $A_n$ to $\mu$ depends on the standard deviation of the population (kept roughly constant here). All graphs
show high variability at the left (for small sample sizes), but 'settle down' to
better behavior at the right (for large sample sizes).
Examples, programmed in R statistical software, are easily adaptable to
other distributions

**Normal data:** Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{5000}$ be independent and
distributed as $\mathsf{Norm}(100, 15); \sigma = 15.$ Look at a graph of 
$A_n = \bar X_n = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ against $n,$ for $n = 1, \dots, m = 5000.$ [In this case, $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$ exactly. But that is a separate issue from convergence of $\bar X$ to $\mu$ according to LLN.]

```
m = 5000; x = rnorm(m, 100, 15); n = 1:m; a = cumsum(x)/n
plot(n, a, type="l", lwd=2, col="blue", ylim=c(90,110))
abline(h = 100, col="green3")
```

[image]

**Exponential data:** Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{5000}$ be independent and
distributed as $\mathsf{Exp}(rate=1/15), \sigma = 15.$ Look at a graph of 
$A_n = \bar X_n = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ against $n.$ [For very large $n,\,
A_n - \mu$ is approximately normal with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ But that is due to the CLT, not the WLLN.]

```
m = 5000; x = rexp(m, 1/15); n = 1:m; a = cumsum(x)/n
plot(n, a, type="l", lwd=2, col="blue", ylim=c(5,25))
abline(h = 15, col="green3")
```

[image]

**Uniform data:** Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{5000}$ be independent and
distributed as $\mathsf{Unif}(75,125), \sigma = 50/\sqrt{12} \approx 14.43.$ Look at a graph of 
$A_n = \bar X_n = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ against $n.$ [Even for moderate $n,\,
A_n - \mu$ is approximately normal with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$]

```
m = 5000; x = runif(m, 75, 125); n = 1:m; a = cumsum(x)/n
plot(n, a, type="l", lwd=2, col="blue", ylim=c(90,110))
abline(h = 100, col="green3")
```

[image]

Comment: Does $\frac{X_{1}+...+X_{n}}{n}$ has a gaussian distribution ?

Comment: If data are $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ then $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$ exactly. If population has mean $\mu$ and SD $\sigma,$ but is not normal, then for large enough $n,$ by Central Limit Theorem, $\bar X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$ // Added remark to 'Normal' section, in [ ].

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended $P\left(\left | \frac{X_{1}+...+X_{n}}{n} -\mu\right | \geq \epsilon \right) \to 0$ : otherwise consider the case with negative $\mu$

If each of the $X_i$ has finite variance $\sigma^2$ then, in a Central Limit Theorem sense,   $\left | \frac{X_{1}+...+X_{n}}{n} -\mu\right |$ could be approximated for large $n$ by a  [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) with scale parameter $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, i.e. with a density function which looks like the positive half of a bell curve which narrows as $n$ increases

Comment: Do you know a simulator so to see what happens when i sum the $X_{i}$s  and then what happens when i divide by n and substract by $\mu $ ?

Comment: You would need to generate the $X_i$s.  You could then simulate this yourself.